# Rails collection select when collection is way big

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form partial inside which I select associated users through a `multiple: true` collection select:

```
    = f.collection_select(:user_ids, User.all, :id, :email, {selected: @limit_group.user_ids, include_blank: true}, {multiple: true, "data-placeholder" => "Add users to group"})
```

But how can I do this more efficiently to avoid big load times when the database has like thousands of users?

Comment: 1 - There are more efficient ways to have a form select a user than a drop down when you have thousands of choices.
2 - A list that should be used often should be put in cache.

Comment: Yeah - 1000's of users in a select box just isn't feasible. What's the user story you're trying to create?

Comment: As specified by @muichkine drop down for such records is not the best way, add a text field instead drop down and search users there and add them in an array by using some jquery tricks and post that array with your form when you are going to submit that form.

Answer (score 1):

You'll be better using something called [`AutoComplete / LiveSearch`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iMz8HmrQ350) with a text box (like `Pardeep Saini` mentioned).

We've done this before:

[image]

You could achieve this relatively simply:

```
= f.text_field :user_ids, placeholder: "Search for users"
```

You'd then have to use `javascript`:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("keyup", "input[type=text]#user_ids", function(){
   $.getJSON("users/search", {name: $(this).val()}).done(function(json){
      var users = [];
      $.each(json.users, function(user) {
         users.push("<a href=\"#\" id="+ user.id +">" + user.name + "</a>");
      });
      $(".search").html(users).show();
   });
});

$(document).on("click", ".search a", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   // add hidden field with user name to form
});
```

You'd have to back it up with the relevant controller action:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users do
   get :search, on: :collection
end

#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def search
     @users = User.where("name LIKE ?", "%" + params[:name] + "%")
     respond_to do |format| 
         format.json (render json: @users.to_json)
     end
  end
end
```

The above code should be refactored.

--

To get this working with *multiple* values would be a little bit more involved. It could be done, but you'd have to do it like the `tags` setup in StackOverflow...

[image]

The way they do that is to basically use a similar principle to the above (each `tag` will be a returned piece of data from the search).

---

Here's the actual code we used in the cosmetics example above:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/extra/jquery.livesearch.js
(function($) {
  $.searchbox = {}

  $.extend(true, $.searchbox, {
    settings: {
        url: 'search',
        param: 'search',
        dom_id: '#livesearch',
        minChars: 2,
        loading_css: '#livesearch_loading',
        del_id: '#livesearch_del'
    },

    loading: function() {
        $($.searchbox.settings.loading_css).show()
    },

    idle: function() {
        $($.searchbox.settings.loading_css).hide()
    },

    start: function() {
      $.searchbox.loading()
      $(document).trigger('before.searchbox')
    },

    stop: function() {
      $.searchbox.idle()
      $(document).trigger('after.searchbox')
    },

    kill: function() {
        $($.searchbox.settings.dom_id).fadeOut(50)
        $($.searchbox.settings.dom_id).html('')
        $($.searchbox.settings.del_id).fadeOut(100)
    },

    reset: function() {
        $($.searchbox.settings.dom_id).html('')
        $($.searchbox.settings.dom_id).fadeOut(50)
        $('#SearchSearch').val('')
        $($.searchbox.settings.del_id).fadeOut(100)
    },

    process: function(terms) {

        if(/\S/.test(terms)) {
            $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url:  $.searchbox.settings.url,
                    data: {search: terms.trim()},
                    complete: function(data) {  
                        $($.searchbox.settings.del_id).fadeIn(50)
                        $($.searchbox.settings.dom_id).html(data.responseText)

                        if (!$($.searchbox.settings.dom_id).is(':empty')) {
                            $($.searchbox.settings.dom_id).fadeIn(100)
                        }

                        $.searchbox.stop();
                    }
                });
            return false;
        }else{
            $.searchbox.kill();
        }
    }
  });

  $.fn.searchbox = function(config) {
        var settings = $.extend(true, $.searchbox.settings, config || {})

        $(document).trigger('init.searchbox')
        $.searchbox.idle()

        return this.each(function() {
            var $input = $(this)

            $input
            .keyup(function() { 
                if ($input.val() != this.previousValue) {

                    if(/\S/.test($input.val().trim()) &&  $input.val().trim().length > $.searchbox.settings.minChars){ 
                        $.searchbox.start()
                        $.searchbox.process($input.val())
                    }else{
                        $.searchbox.kill()
                    }

                    this.previousValue = $input.val()

                }
            })
        })
    }
})(jQuery);
```

... and ...

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).ready( function() {

   var base_url = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host;

    $('#SearchSearch').searchbox({
       url: base_url + '/search/',
       param: 'search',
       dom_id: '#livesearch',
       loading_css: '#livesearch_loading'
    })      

});
$(document).on('click', '#livesearch_del', function() { $.searchbox.reset(); }) 
$(document).on('submit', '#SearchForm', function() { $.searchbox.kill(); });
$(document).on('click', '.livesearch_results tr', function() { window.location = $('a:first', this).attr('href'); });
```

The routes & controller:

```
#config/routes.rb
match 'search(/:search)', :to => 'products#search', :as => :search, via: [:get, :post]

#app/models/product.rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   def self.search(search)
        where("name LIKE ? OR description LIKE ?", "%#{search}%",  "%#{search}%").take(5)
   end
end

#app/controllers/product_controller.rb
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
    def search      
        @products = Product.search params[:search]
        respond_to do |format|
            format.js   { render :partial => "elements/livesearch", :locals => {:search => @products, :query => params[:search]} }
            format.html { 
                render :index
            }
        end
    end
end
```

The views:

```
#app/views/elements/_livesearch.html.erb
<div class="livesearch_container">
    <table class="livesearch_results">
        <%  unless search.blank? %>

            <% search.each_with_index do |item,i| %>

                <% pos ||= '' %>
                <% if (i == 0) then pos = 'first' end %>
                <% if (i == search.size - 1) then pos += ' last' end %>

                <tr data-link="<%= "/#{item.slug}" %>" class="<%= "#{pos}" %>">
                    <td class="image">
                        <% model = item.images.first || item.images.build %>
                        <%= image_tag(model.image.url(:thumb), :title => item.name, data: {"placement" => "left"}, :height => "85") %><br/>
                    </td>
                    <td class="information">
                        <%= link_to image_tag(item.brand.images.first.image.url(:thumb), :width => "55", :title => "View #{item.brand.name}"), "/#{item.brand.slug}", :class => "brand" if defined?(item.brand.images.first) %>
                        <div class="name"><%= link_to item.name, "/#{item.slug}" %></div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="price">
                        <%= number_to_currency(item.price, unit: "&pound;") %>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <% end %>

            <tr class="results"><td colspan="3"><%= link_to "See all #{search.size} results here »", search_path(query) %></td></tr>

        <% else %>

            <tr class="results"><td colspan="3"><%= link_to 'No results found', search_path(query) %></td></tr>

        <% end %>
    </table> 
</div>
```

---

I also made a `gist` here: https://gist.github.com/richpeck/2310ff3ab1ffcd6a9138